# Change default port 3000 on Rocket.Chat installed using Snap

Tags: port, rocket.chat

I have installed the Awsome Rocket.Chat on Ubuntu 16.04 using Snap, however i can no figure out how to change the server from running on 
http://DOMAIN:3000 to simply http://DOMAIN ..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Currently the Rocket.Chat snap doesn't have the option to change the port its listening on.  In the near future we will be adding support for this, as well as to add ssl.

But for now our suggestion would be to use a reverse proxy like nginx in front of the snap.

If you decide to use nginx you can do the following:

Install nginx: `sudo apt install nginx`

Then edit `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` with your favorite editor

and put the following contents in it:

```
# Upstreams
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# HTTPS Server
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name your-domain.com;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/rocketchat.access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don’t use SSLv3 ref: POODLE

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Replacing `your-domain.com` with your domain.

Once you save then restart nginx: `sudo services nginx restart`

Comment: This answer is outdated - you can now simply use Caddy: https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/snaps/autossl
Just note, you'll need to use Caddy on port 80 at first so it can present the acme challenge to LE to obtain an SSL cert.  You may also want to disable the "restart on failure" behavior of Caddy to avoid hitting the LE rate limit.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39202645/2970321

Comment: You are right this answer is outdated.  Caddy is now included and would be the recommended route

Answer (score 3):

You can define a rule in iptables

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

and then save the rule by this command

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/snaps/#how-do-i-change-rocketchat-port-mongo_url-and-mongo_oplog_url-in-my-snap) states :

Starting from release 0.73, it is possible to configure these environmental variables through snap hooks like this:

```
sudo snap set rocketchat-server port=<another-port>
sudo snap set rocketchat-server mongo-url=mongodb://<your-url>:<your-port>/<your-db-name>
sudo snap set rocketchat-server mongo-oplog-url=mongodb://<your-url>:<your-port>/local
```

Remember to restart rocket.chat service after setting new values:

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service
```

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me.

```
root@sathish:/snap/rocketchat-server/580/bin# sudo snap run rocketchat-server.initcaddy
Replace /var/snap/rocketchat-server/580/Caddyfile with your own to customize reverse proxy
```

Edit the file

> /var/snap/rocketchat-server/580/Caddyfile

Replace :8080 to :80

```
http://yourdomain:80
proxy / localhost:3000 {
  websocket
  transparent
}
```

Restart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy
```

Check the Port for confirmation

```
netstat -plnatu | grep :80
```